# Mysql 3 tables, copy column

Tags: mysql

I have three mysql table from same database Db1.

Three tables have following columns.

Table 1: 
Name
City
Branch

Table 2:
Age
Address
Country

Table 3:
No columns.

I want to copy Table1.Name and Table2.Age to Table 3. How can I do it?

Comment: do you want to copy just one record or all the names and age values to table 3?

Comment: Please provide actual schema and explain relationships between tables.

Comment: If that is what your schema looks like then it would be impossible to accurately programatically fill in table 3. There isn't a primary key or foreign key for either table 1 or table 2 leaving no way to accurately assign the correct age to name. We either need more information or your schema needs to be reworked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes little sense if table1 and table2 can not be joined and table 3 doesn't have the 2 columns. If you can join:

```
insert into table3 (name, age)
select table1.name, table2.age
from table1 join table2 on (table1.columnToLinkFromTable1 = table2.columnToLinkFromTable2)
```

You could also do it like this, but of course it doesn't make much sense:

```
insert into table3 (name, age)
    select table1.name, table2.age
    from table1, table2
```

Comment: Thankyou I might have got answer from mihaisimi, it was general two columns I was interested to put in table 3.